# need the same Class in JS and PHP, what is the proper way to handle this?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I need a whole lot of class'es to be available both in JS and PHP (in JS for a GUI, in PHP for code execution).

Im reluctant to write all classes twice, because even though each class is only small by itself, there are lot of them.

So far i only did the JS side:

examples

```
function BaseLaser(parentId, arc1, arc2, arc3, arc4){
    this.parentId = parentId;
    this.arc1 // etc
    this.draw = function(){
       //draw on canvas
    }
}


function HeavyLaser(parentId, arc1, arc2, arc3, arc4){
    BaseLaser.call(this, parentId, arc1, arc2, arc3, arc4);
    this.name = "Heavy Laser";
    this.structure = 8;
    this.armour = 2;
    this.damage = 100;
    this.optRange = 800;
    this.dmgDecay = 5;
    this.accDecay = 50;
    this.shots = 1;
    this.reload = 2;
    this.beamColorA = "#EA0000";
    this.beamColorB = "orange";
    this.beamWidth = 3;
    this.rakeTime = 70;
}
HeavyLaser.prototype = Object.create(BaseLaser.prototype);

function MediumLaser(parentId, arc1, arc2, arc3, arc4){
    BaseLaser.call(this, parentId, arc1, arc2, arc3, arc4);
    this.name = "Medium Laser";
    this.structure = 8;
    this.armour = 2;
    this.damage = 100;
    this.optRange = 450;
    this.dmgDecay = 10;
    this.accDecay = 70;
    this.shots = 1;
    this.reload = 2;
    this.beamWidth = 2;
    this.rakeTime = 50;
}
MediumLaser.prototype = Object.create(BaseLaser.prototype);
```

`BaseLaser` class has a few more functions.

I need all of the generic attributes of HeavyLaser and MediuMLaser on both client and server.

Im under the impression i should recreate these (Heavy and MediumLaser) and instead of having proper classes on JS, do them in PHP and transfer then as generic JSON objects as a kind of "template" to the client. 
There, i can use the JSON string to create "custom" objects from.

Would that be the correct way - or how is this problem, which i believe occurs regulary, best solved ?

thanks

Comment: Why do you need the _same_ classes? I've never actually heard of an architecture that uses 1:1 mapping of classes between layers. Well, aside from maybe Transfer Objects but those are dumb (not derogative) and used for data transmission.

Comment: Im no professional. Im doing a browser-based game. As you can see, the classes hold various information about weapon-systems, this information needs to be displayed in the user GUI. The same values are also used on the server, when player actions are being resolved (math).
So i believe i need the "Systems" and more on both ends.

Comment: Well, you don't need the same _classes_ then, you need the same _data_. You _could_ represent that as the same classes but it would lead to your application being very tightly coupled. The better thing to do is to indeed have the classes "twice", only I imagine you don't really need to have that much code for each - you should be able to use inheritance, composition, and others to define few "base" classes and derive stiff from there. It doesn't seem like they would do that much anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best share way here is JSON as it uderstandable by both JS and PHP, but it can be used in different ways.

The possible solutions here are at least 2:

1. Store default values in JSON and load each model defaults on backend from these files so use them to instantiate your objects on frontend from these files as well. Kinda config approach.
2. Or request defaults via **AJAX**. Thus you can avoid using separate JSON files and set defaults more native way on backend and transfer/alter/use it without any overhead.